# SQL multiple tables reach

Tags: sql

I have this chunk of code here, thing is it query selected "TestLog" and shows:

- name,
- schema,
- rowcount,
- totalspace,
- usedspace,....

Thing is I need this information to be queried for more than one table, lets say  a 5 specific ones...  can anyone help out?

```
USE myDB
GO 

SELECT
  t.name                                                 AS TableName,
  s.name                                                 AS SchemaName,
  p.rows                                                 AS RowCounts,
  SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 / 1024                          AS TotalSpaceMB,
  SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 / 1024                           AS UsedSpaceMB,
  (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 / 1024    AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM
  sys.tables t
  INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
  INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    t.name = ('TestLog') 
      AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND i.object_id > 255
GROUP BY
  t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY
  t.name;
GO
```

Comment: `WHERE
    t.name IN ('TestLog', 'table2', 'table3', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

It works as below:

```
-- specific tables 
 WHERE
    t.name in ('Test1' , 'Test2' , 'Test3') 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0   
    AND i.object_id > 255

-- one specific table 
 WHERE
    t.name = 'TestLog' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0   
    AND i.object_id > 255

-- specific tables with test in front 
  WHERE
    t.name like 'Test%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0   
    AND i.object_id > 255
```

Comment: yes, i finished the script,  tested it , and it works like a charm

Comment: @600vka, so please accept answer. I know it was actually answered (in comment by jarlh) but otherwise your question remain unanswered...